# Proving that $f(n)=n$ if $f(n+1)>f(f(n))$

Tags: functional-equations

How can we prove that if $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a function so that $f(n+1)>f(f(n))$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

This is problem 6 from the IMO 1977. I found it in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1448627346).

Comment: Here is   http://www.amazon.com/15-000-problems-Mathematical-Olympiads/dp/1448627346/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1354422850&sr=1-1&keywords=15000+problems+from+mathematical+olympiads

Comment: [Beni Bogoşel](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/7327/beni-bogosel) posted a [very similar problem](https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/functional-equation-on-positive-integers/) on his blog, and indicated (at the time) that he might be willing to add a solution. Unfortunately there's not any more detailed attribution.

Comment: IMO 1977 problem 6. My g/f found it online:)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Claim 1**: If $f(k) = 0$ then $k =0$.

*Proof*: Suppose not.  Then there exists $k$ such that $0 = f(k) > f(f(k-1))$, which is not possible, as $f: \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$.

**Claim 2**: $f(0) = 0$.

*Proof*: Let $S = \{f(k) | k > 0\}$.  Let $a$ be the smallest number in $S$.  Then there exists $k >0$ such that $a = f(k) > f(f(k-1))$.  But this means $f(k-1) = 0$.  Thus $k=1$, and $f(0) = 0$.

**Claim 3:** $f(n) = n$.

*Proof*: Assume, for all $0 \leq m < n$, that $f(k) = m$ iff $k = m$.  Now we proceed as in the proofs of Claims 1 and 2.

If $f(k) = n$, then $f(f(k-1)) < n$, which means $k-1 = f(k-1) = f(f(k-1)) < n$.  So $k < n+1$, which means that $k = n$.

Let $S = \{f(k) | k > n\}$.  Let $a$ be the smallest number in $S$.  Thus there exists $k >n$ such that $a = f(k) > f(f(k-1))$.  Therefore $f(k-1) \leq n$.  But if $f(k-1) < n$, then $f(k-1) = k-1$, and so $k \leq n$.  But $k>n$.  Therefore, $f(k-1) = n$, and so $k= n+1$ and $f(n) = n$.

Comment: Mike. I do not understand your test sequence. In the penultimate sentence why if $ f (k-1) <n $ then $ f (k-1) = k-1 $?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: If $f(k-1)<n$ then the induction assumption "for all $0 \leq m < n$, $f(k)=m$ iff $k=m$ " applies.  Thus $f(k-1)=k-1$.

Comment: Mike, if $f(k-1)<n$ and if we apply the induction hypothesis then we have $f(f(k-1))=f(k-1)$ and only if f is injective we can say that  $f(k-1)=k-1$.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: No, I'm not making any global assumptions about $f$ being injective. The induction hypothesis is that if $f$ maps $k$ to any value $m$ smaller than $n$ then $k$ must be $m$, and so $f$ maps $k$ to itself.  I suppose the induction hypothesis could be thought of implying that $f$ is injective in a local sense, but I didn't think of it that way.  In other words, $f(k-1) = k-1$ precisely because $f(k-1) < n$.  If $f(k-1) \geq n$, then we wouldn't be able to claim that $f(k-1) = k-1$ (at least at this point in the proof.)

Comment: Mike. In the last line why if $f(k-1) = n$, and so $k= n+1$?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: We know $f(k-1) \leq n$.  Since $f(k-1) < n$ implies $k \leq n$, and we know $k > n$, we must have $f(k-1) = n$.    In the previous paragraph we showed that if $f(k) = n$ then $k=n$.  Therefore, $f(k-1) = n$ implies $k-1=n$, and so $k=n+1$.

Comment: Mike. Why in the previous paragraph  $f(k-1)=k-1$?

Comment: Mike. In the claim 3, with the second paragraph you show that if $k\geq n$ and $f(k)=n$ then $k=n$. Then why you write the third paragraph?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: In the second paragraph of Claim 3, $f(f(k-1)) < n$ means that we can apply the induction hypothesis.  Thus $f(f(k-1)) = f(k-1)$.  But then this means that $f(k-1) < n$, so we can apply the induction hypothesis again to get $f(k-1) = k-1$.

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: The second paragraph of Claim 3 involves a conditional: IF $f(k) = n$ THEN $k=n$.  I don't know at that point that $f$ actually does map $n$ to itself.  The point of paragraph 3 of Claim 3 is to prove that $f$ truly does map $n$ to itself.  There's a parallel here with Claims 1 and 2.  Claim 1 says "if $f(k) = 0$ then $k=0$."  I don't know that $f$ actually does map $0$ to itself until I prove it with Claim 2.

Comment: Excellent Mike. Thanks  :)

Comment: @MikeSpivey: In the proof of claim 3 : from $f(f(k-1))<n$ , how does it follow $f(f(k-1))=f(k-1)$ ?

Comment: @SouvikDey: Since $f$ maps $f(k-1)$ to some value strictly smaller than $n$, the induction hypothesis applies, and so $f(f(k-1)) = f(k-1)$.  (The induction hypothesis is stated in the first paragraph of Claim 3; namely, that if $f$ maps $k$ to some value $0 \leq m < n$, then the input $k$ is equal to the output $m$.  The claim $f(f(k-1)) = f(k-1)$ is just saying that the input $f(k-1)$ is equal to the output $f(f(k-1))$.)

Comment: Doesn't the second claim already follow from the first claim?

Answer (score 5):

Another proof :

1. We first show the property $P_n$ is true for all $n$
   $\\$ $P_n : (\forall k \geq n \implies f(k) \geq n)$

   **Proof by Induction :**
   (i) $P_0$ is true, since $\forall k \geq 0 ( f(k) \geq 0)$
   (ii) $\forall n$, if $P_n$ is true, then
   $\forall k \geq n+1 ; k-1 \geq n$ then $f(k-1) \geq n$ then $f(f(k-1)) \geq n$ and
   $f(k) > f(f(k-1)) \geq n$ thus $f(k) \geq n+1$
   Therefore $P_{n+1}$ is true.
2. $\forall n$, since $P_n$ is true, take $k=n$, then $f(n) \geq n$
3. Then $\forall n, f(f(n)) \geq f(n)$ then the starting hypothesis yields:
   $\\$  $f(n+1)>f(n)$ then $f$ is strictly growing.
   Thus the starting hypothesis implies : $\forall n, n+1> f(n)$
4. Thus for all $n$, $n+1>f(n)>=n$. Hence, $f(n) = n$

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Attempted solution (Improvements/corrections are greatly welcome!):

Clearly, the function isn't constant on any interval. So it must be either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Suppose the function isn't injective. Then there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$, but $a \neq b$. So either $a>b$ or $a<b$. WLOG, let $a>b$. Then $a = b+m$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, $f(a) = f(b+m) > f(f(b+(m-1)) > f(f(f(b+m-2) > ... >f(f(...(f(b))...)$. Now, suppose, WLOG that $f$ is increasing (if $f$ is decreasing, then there is also a contradiction). Then $f(f(...(f(b))...) > f(b)$. But $f(b) = f(a)$. Thus, we have a contradiction. So, $f$ must be injective.

Now, apply $f^{-1}$ on both sides, and you get that $n+1 > f(n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Clearly, if $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n) = a*n+b$, where $a \neq 1$ and $b \neq 0$, then it would contradict $n+1 > f(n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now it's just left to see what happens if there exists an $n'$ where $f(n') \neq n'$. In such a case, $f(n')>n'$ or $f(n')<n'$. Check that both cases still lead to contradictions.

I think if you can somehow rule out that $f$ is decreasing, then this might work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice. I think I've completed my answer for this question, and will be sure to follow your advice in the future.

Comment: Cubby why $f$ is increase?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't have to be increasing. Let me improve my solution.

Comment: Ah, now I remember why it has to be strictly increasing. Because if it is strictly decreasing, then $f(0) < 0$, which implies that $f(0) \notin \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Why can't it be a constant in any interval?

Comment: Remember why? You have seen this before?

Comment: Not constant on any interval is not the same as strictly increasing or decreasing.  The sequence that alternates 0,1 is not constant nor strictly increasing or decreasing.